# UML class diagram not generating for C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I have read several questions about this problem at SO but the suggested solution is to do the UPDATE 4. I have already **installed update-4** to my **VS 2012 Ultimate**. But still I am not able to get the UML diagram.

My Step:

- Go to the architecture tab in VS 2012 Ultimate
- select "New Diagram"
- select "UML Class Diagram"
- then choose the name etc.
- the go to "Architecture Explorer"
- Drop the classes for which you want to generate UML diagram.

Just to check if there is some other probelm, I wrote a simple program of two classes. In this program, the variable of one class is set by the variable of second class. But there is no UML diagram get generated for the following program.

**ERRORS:**

```
Reverse engineer C++ type is not supported. Some DGML node(s) will be skipped during the process. Please see warnings for details.

(0) type(s) fully reverse engineered.
```

**Warnings:**

```
<Warning Timestamp="2015-09-01T09:45:05" Importance="Medium" Text="Reverse engineer C++ type 'Class1' is skipped." />
  <Warning Timestamp="2015-09-01T09:45:05" Importance="Medium" Text="Reverse engineer C++ type 'Class2' is skipped." />
```

**My code:**

***Class1***

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H

class Class1 { 
    private:    
        int value;

    public:
        void setValue(int value);
        void showValue();
};

#endif
```

***Class2:***

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include "Header1.h"

class Class2 {  
    public:
        int secondClassValue; 
        void setValue(int val);
        Class1 *class1;

};
#endif
```

***main():***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header1.h"
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

void Class1::setValue(int value) {
    this->value = value;
}

void Class1::showValue() {
    cout<<"The value of second class variable is: "<<this->value<<endl;
}


void Class2::setValue(int val) {
    secondClassValue = val;
}


int main() {
    Class1 *class1 = new Class1;
    Class2 *class2 = new Class2;

    class2->setValue(10);
    class1->setValue(class2->secondClassValue);

    //See the set value
    class1->showValue();

    delete class1;
    delete class2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are warnings that visual studio generates?

Comment: @Jepessen: I have updated my question to include warnings. Please have a look at it.

Comment: What if you write class definition in their own .cpp files instead that inside the main.cpp?

Comment: @Jepessen: that I did not try but I don't think that it will affect anything becasue the UML diagram is supposed to be generated using the header files. I have to drag and drop only the header files not the .cpp files to generate UML class diagram.

Comment: Then the `Reverse engineer C++ type is not supported` message can simply mean that C++ is not supported in this tool...

Comment: @Jepessen: And that is my question. I think that it is possible to get the UML class diagram of C++ classes too.